# How to apply bootstrap to editor for in asp.net?

Tags: html, css, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to make my website look a little better so i was going to pep it up with Bootstrap. 
I use quite a lot of forms that use this format

```
@Html.EditorFor(m => m.QuizName);

@Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.QuizName)
```

From bootstrap there is this class: `'form-control'` but how do i apply that to the code above?

Comment: Which version of MVC? (your can only add html attributes using `EditorFor()` if using MVC-5.1 or higher as indicated in mxmissile's answer)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `additionalViewData` object argument in Asp.Net MVC 5 to add classes like this:

```
@Html.EditorFor(x => x.QuizName, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
```